# Linux issue writing files and setting group to apache when the gid=501(www)

Tags: linux, file-ownership

Im Working on an application that requires several users to have access to a directory called previews.

So I set the primary group of each user to be `www`

When the files have a group of `www` the application works without any issues.

The problem is that the files are created through an http request, meaning that the `apache` user is creating the file.

when i run
`id apache`

i get `uid=48(apache) gid=501(www) groups=501(www),48(apache)`

but the file's owner and group is `apache apache`

i can't figure out how to get apache to create files with owner and group as `apache www`

Thanks in advance. I have spent many days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setgid

In the directory where the files are created, you can set that directory to the group you want and set the setgid bit, so all the files in that directory have the same group.

If the directory doesn’t have the group you want, use chown.

chown username:www directory/

ls -lld directory/ should have “username www”.

chmod g+s directory/

ls -lld should show an “s” where the group “x” was, drwxr-sr-...

cd directory/

touch testFile

ls -ll testFile

The file testFile should be “username www”.

I don’t know the rules about linking information here, but google “oracle setgid” to find a good document.